# Groovy: Convert string with simple \

Tags: java, groovy, replace, type-conversion, backslash

I'm trying to convert a string I dynamically get, to double the \ or convert them as / (both are ok for me).

It is formated as:

```
d:\code\main
```

I can't edit it at the source.

In my tests, I tried using replace or replaceAll function, with \ to 5 \\\, but I always run into this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: 
script15181726196231935876660.groovy: 4: unexpected char: '\' @ line 4, column 17. 
String main = "d:\code\main\blabla\blabla"
^ 

1 error 

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:302) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:119) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:131) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:359) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:137) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108) 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236) ...
```

Is there a way convert or rebuild this variable without falling in this Java error ?

Thanks

Comment: Use single quotes instead - `String main = 'd:\code\main\blabla\blabla'`

Comment: I just tried, but I get the same error :(

Comment: My mistake - in case of single quotes you also have to escape \ character - `String main = 'd:\\code\\main\\blabla\\blabla'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dollar slashy string` and `Slashy string` both allow backslashes.

```
def s1 = /d:\code/
def s2 = $/d:\code/$
s1.equals(s2) // true
```

The `slashy string` has exactly one case where the backslash is a special symbol - if it comes before the forward slash:

```
def s3 = /This - \/ - is the forward slash/ 
// This - / - is the forward slash
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_summary_table).

Answer (score 1):

The `\` charactere is escape char https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character. So, to use it as a literal value use `\\` instead.

`String main = "d:\\code\\main\\blabla\\blabla"`

Comment: It is my issue, the base string I will get in the final script don't have double backslash.
I need to find a way to convert it to be able to work with after.

Comment: For each backslash use `\\ `. If you wants a double backslash use `\\\\ `.

Comment: But Java crash when it just try to read the initial string, so I can't even try to do a replace function or anything else on it as far as I tested.

Comment: Java understands files with `/` notation... In your case, Shoudn't be better to use `String main = "d://code/main/blabla/blabla"` ?

Comment: I understand your point of view, my issue is that the beginning of the path will be given by my build system, and I will be not able to edit it.
I will add blabla myself, but "d:\code\main" will be get like this sadly.